# What should I do when I decide to give up on a question I asked?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

Sometimes I ask a question, but at some point I am no longer interested in testing answers to see if they work. There's a variety of more or less valid reasons for this.

- It could be because the answer is old and I no longer have or care about the project.
- It could be because the suggested answer is particularly difficult to apply,
  and I'd rather live with the issue.
- It could be because I found a work around that isn't really an answer to the question, so I no longer need an answer.

I'm unsure what to do in these cases.

- Do I delete the question?
- Do I mark an answer correct if others have up voted it and it appears correct?
- Do I leave the question alone?

What is the best course of action?

Comment: Is it likely to be useful to future users as it stands?  Would it be more useful if you added your workaround as a self-answer?

Comment: @MartinJames I try to make every question useful to future users. As for an example where a workaround isn't a proper answer, I had code that looped through files in a directory very slowly, my workaround was just to delete a bunch of files. I wouldn't feel comfortable posting that as an answer.

Comment: 'I wouldn't feel comfortable posting that as an answer' LOL, me neither:)

Comment: leave it alone or delete it. no harm either way

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since there's already an upvoted answer, you couldn't delete the question even if you wanted to.  If the question was eligible for deletion, and there was really nothing of value there (either no answers, or a clearly bad answer) then sure, feel free to delete it (someone else with the same problem can just re-ask the question), but if there's useful content there for a future reader there's no reason to delete the question.

You most certainly shouldn't accept an answer just because other people thought it was a good answer.  If you've evaluated it and determined its usefulness, vote accordingly, and if you haven't, and therefore don't know how useful it is, don't vote.

Doing nothing is a perfectly valid option in this situation.  Certainly no actions are *necessary* on your part.

Comment: This makes me feel much less guilty. That said, I'll of course always try to commit to any questions I ask. Thanks!