# Old question received an answer: Not able to verify & accept?

Tags: discussion, answers

A few months ago I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50681546/aws-cognito-enabling-mfa-error-mfa-cannot-be-turned-off-if-an-sms-role-is-c/) and got no immediate answers. I have since solved the problem manually.

Today I received an answer, but **I'm not able to verify if the answer is correct** and thereby not able to accept the answer.

How should I respond to answers I'm no longer able to verify?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355055/what-to-do-when-i-decide-to-give-up-on-a-question-i-asked

Comment: Also related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372537/is-this-improper-behavior-op-i-have-not-verified-the-solution-as-i-had-to#comment621049_372537